# Enabling 'App Groups' in Xcode 6.3.2 shows error in steps

Tags: ios, xcode6, watchkit

I am trying to enable 'App Groups' in my Xcode 6.3.2, but I am getting errors as in the image below

[image]

I have done everything as per the steps mentioned different tutorials. When I had the issue earlier, I tried with some other Apple id and that also didn't work. But when I switched back to the previous account, it worked! Not sure what really happened. And it was working till yesterday. Yesterday, due to some other issue I cleared my machine Keychain and after that it is not working again.

I have seen some other posts mentioned about this issue, but for me the situation is different. If someone gets any idea, why its happening so, please share your thoughts.

As I am using my Company's Developer account, I am not allowed to click 'Fix Issue' button to let the Xcode to fix the issue itself! :(

Comment: Login through your developer account and create a App groups,have u done that?

Comment: Yes, I logged into developer account and enabled and created App Groups. The point is, it got worked till I clear my Keychain.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that you're not allowed to click Fix Issue? Is there a problem with the steps it takes? A company policy against clicking Xcode's fix issue button? This seems like the quickest and easiest fix, and you should talk to your company, because otherwise we would jump through a lot of hoops.

Comment: Yea, I know it is the easiest way to click on Fix issues to resolve the problem. But usually they don't let us do anything which makes any modifications at Developer account certificates or any files. I am working in an MNC and they have lot of apps running with this account. If nothing worked, I will ask them for permission. But before that I have to make sure that, there should not be any other work around to fix this issue. Or if they find any solution later, that would be a problem for me.. So if someone can point out any possible reasons, it would be grateful.

Comment: Or someone can please share the details about how to set up certificates and all for App Groups. Including bundle id's, provisioning profiles etc Because, the admin of the company account can only create and share these files with me.